# Alternate phrase for hope you are doing well

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

What does this phrase mean and when do you use it
"I hope you’re having a two-coffee (versus a four-coffee) day"

Thanks

Priya

Comment: There isn’t a set meaning. It could be a stern admonishment to limit caffeine intake or a friendly wish for a day that doesn’t require so much artificial stimulation to get through. It depends on a lot more than the words spoken.

Comment: I would be baffled by that greeting. Note that it needed a parenthesised explanation, and is far too elaborate. It could mean that I didn't have time for my normal 4 coffees, or that I needed more than my normal 2 coffees. Usually, we say something rhetorical like "How are you?"

Comment: 2 coffees are the oft-prescribed beverage to produce a healthy bowel movement for many middle-aged OCD sufferers..:-)

Answer (score -1):

The quote by George Jung, sounds fine.  However be aware that Jung was a notorious drug smuggler in his early years, and the inspiration for the movie "Blow".

I do like the first sentence if left to stand alone. *(May the wind always be at your back and the sun upon your face.)*

“May the wind always be at your back and the sun upon your face. And may the wings of destiny carry you aloft to dance with the stars.”

― George Jung, Blow by Blow